# Would using an interation count greater than 1 with a random keyfile of length greater than the master key be of any benefit?

Tags: luks

If I were to have a 4096-bit file of random data (/dev/random) used as a keyfile for LUKS, would there be any benefit to having a key iteration count higher than 1?

My reasoning is that the attacker could choose to guess the contents of the 4096-bit file (very very hard), the 256-bit master key (still hard, but easier than the 4096-bit file), or the potentially key-stretched 256-bit key derived from tbe keyfile that would decrypt the master key (equivalent in difficulty to the master key).

Am I correct in believing that an iteration count of 1 is no less secure than a count of 100000 for the keyfile?

Comment: Your question would probably be better (and more quickly answered!) on the crypto.stackexchange.com site. I've alerted the moderators so they can review it. It might help if you could comment yourself whether you think it should be moved or not.